# Can't Post data from postman to database with express

Tags: express, postman

I am unable to Post data from postman to mysql database
I'm using express

I have tried using Body and Raw x-wwww-form-urlencoded

Here is my code (Yes everything is in the same file I know it's not a good thing I'm sorry)

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.send({ error: true, message: 'hello' })
});
// connection configurations
var dbConn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'testexpress'
});

// connect to database
dbConn.connect(); 



// Add a new user  
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {

    let user = req.body.user;

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide user' });
    }

    dbConn.query("INSERT INTO users SET ? ", { user: user }, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'New user has been created successfully.' });
    });
});

// set port
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port 3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

here is my screenshot error from Postman and my database

[image: Postman error]

[image: Database]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `user` to the POST request?

Comment: Not working because in my database i don't have "user" in my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this. It should work

```
// Add a new user  
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {

    let user = [req.body]
    console.log(user);

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide user' });
    }

    dbConn.query("INSERT INTO users SET ? ", user, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'New user has been created successfully.' });
    });
});
```

Your code is showing this error message `error:true, message: 'Please provide user` because  everytime in your code the condition  `if (!user)` is executed, because **let user = req.body.user** is going to give **undefined** value so you are going to get that error and the rest of the code will never execute then
.

Comment: it's working thank you so much ! I am having the same issue with my request put(update)  i have          `let user_id = req.body.user_id;
    let user = [req.body]; `   any ideas ?

Comment: no for, updating data in db, you have to take user_id input like this `let user_id = req.params.user_id ` and also you have to pass it to url `/user/${id}` and then just write sql update command